# Component doesn's render on state change

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to mock reading of continuous data in batches in React. Currently the mock data has 10 objects and I'm trying to load 2 every 5 seconds into the state. I'm using an interval which stops when the state has all the values.  The state updates correctly with the timer but the component is rendered only after the first state change which confuses me. I have the feeling that it is possibly a concurrency problem but I could be wrong.

```
export default class Example extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            batchDataState: []
        };

    }

    interval = 0;
    batchData = [];

    componentDidMount() {
        this.batchData.push(data[this.batchData.length]);
        this.batchData.push(data[this.batchData.length]);
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.loadBatchedData(), 5000);
    }


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (this.state.batchDataState !== prevState.batchDataState) {
          console.log(this.state.batchDataState)
        }
    }

    stopInterval = () => {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    };


    loadBatchedData = () => {
        if (this.batchData.length < data.length) {
            this.batchData.push(data[this.batchData.length]); //i
            this.batchData.push(data[this.batchData.length]); //i+1
            this.setState({batchDataState: this.batchData}, ()=>  console.log); // changes the state but doesn't lead to rendering
        } else {
             this.stopInterval();
        }
    };
```

Comment: standard ... existing object mutation - use new object in `setState`

Comment: oh... I don't know how I missed this .. Thanks so much!